# Change Font Color on Value Prompt Display Values

Tags: cognos

I'm using Report Studio Version 10.2.2 and I have a question regarding value prompts.

I've got a report with a prompt page that works great. I set up a value prompt as a multi-select, check box group with default selections. I'd like to give a visual queue to the end user by changing the font color for the "Default Selections" to red.

[image]

How do you change the font color for specific display values in a value prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript

You can add an HTML item before the value prompt:

```
<span id="MyList">
```

...and an HTML item after the value prompt...

```
</span>
<style>
.MyRedClass {
    color: #ff0000; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
</style>
<script>
var s = document.getElementById("MyList");

var divCollection = s.getElementsByClassName("clsCheckBoxRow");

var isPositive = function(n) {
    return n > 0;
}

for (var d = 0; d < divCollection.length; d++) {

    switch (true) {
        case isPositive(divCollection[d].innerHTML.indexOf("CORPORATION FOR PROFIT")):
        case isPositive(divCollection[d].innerHTML.indexOf("CORPORATION NON PROFIT")):
        case isPositive(divCollection[d].innerHTML.indexOf("INDIVIDUAL")):
            divCollection[d].classList.add("MyRedClass");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Problems:

- You will need to maintain the list of default values in two places. 
  (Or you could abandon the *Default selections* property and use
  JavaScript to set the defaults.)
- My code looks for a class named
  clsCheckBoxRow.  That may not work for users using a different theme
  (?).  I don't know because I didn't bother testing.
- If any of the default values match text that is in the HTML (other than the value -- unlikely), you'll need to make the search more specific.  (like digging deeper into the DOM)
- This may be challenging to upgrade to the Interactive Viewer in Cognos Analytics.

Comment: Excellent solution. I never would have guessed I could wrap < HTML Item > 's around the prompt value. It works great except for Internet Explorer. Thank you!